# Android Studio: Why my screen with images is lagging?

Tags: android, image, android-studio, imageview, lag

**Description:**

I have an activity which has 9 "Image Views". I`ve put images on them loaded from my drawable-v24 folder. The total weight of 9 images together is 992KB (less than 1 megabyte).

**XML code of images:**

All image views (9) are the same:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_img1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_title"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/img1"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view_background1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:alpha="0.4"
                android:background="@drawable/seleccion_categoria" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#252525"
                android:alpha="0.6"
                android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/img1"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**What did I try?**

I reduced size of the images to 992kb all but my activity is still lagging. I think it is important to say that my activity runs well in one of my phones (Motorola moto e 5), and very bad in my other phone (Motorola Moto g4).

Which is the problem? What do I have to do to delete this lag?

Link to download rar folder with 9 images:
https://www.mediafire.com/file/sbp7g6jozqgzv9a/images_tomas_menniti.rar/file

**Thanks for reading**

Comment: "I reduced size of the images to 992kb" -- if you are referring to the size *on disk*, bear in mind that those images are rather large. If you want to keep them as drawable resources, be sure to put them in `res/drawable-anydpi/` or `res/drawable-nodpi/`, so Android does not try scaling them based on screen density. As it stands, they will take up 10+ MB of heap space. If you have them in a directory like `res/drawable/`, they will take up much more space.

Comment: Hey @CommonsWare and thanks for answering. Yes, i refered to disk size. Let me see if i understood your suggestion: You are saying that i only have to move the images from res/drawable/ to res/drawable-anydpi/ ? If so, where are those folders? in my app i only have drawable and drawable-v24

Comment: "You are saying that i only have to move the images from res/drawable/ to res/drawable-anydpi/ ?" -- I am saying that it will help with memory consumption. I do not know how much of your loading time is coming from memory concerns. "If so, where are those folders?" -- you need to create them. You will need to create many folders as part of your Android app development.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks again for answering. How can i check loading time that comes from memory so i can share it with you?. Last question: What folder do you recommend me to create and why? res/drawable-anydpi/ or res/drawable-nodpi/?